# Is g_ptr_array_add () in GLib thread safe?

Tags: glib

The documentation says:

```
          void  g_ptr_array_insert (GPtrArray *array,
                gint index_,
                gpointer data);
```

> Inserts an element into the pointer array at the given index. The
>   array will grow in size automatically if necessary.

Same question for g_ptr_array_add().
Documentation is silent about thread safety of these functions. The following functions are described expressly to be thread-safe:

```
      g_ptr_array_free ()
      g_ptr_array_ref()
      g_ptr_array_unref ()
```

What if multiple-threads execute g_ptr_array_insert() at the same time on the same array of pointers? Do I have to provide thread safety myself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it's not thread-safe (just as *almost* all GLib data types; [source](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-Threads.html#glib-Threads.description), see “you must coordinate accesses…”). Chances are that 
two threads enter marked line simultaneously.

```c
static void
g_ptr_array_maybe_expand (GRealPtrArray *array,
                          gint           len)
{
  if ((array->len + len) > array->alloc)
    {
      guint old_alloc = array->alloc;
      array->alloc = g_nearest_pow (array->len + len);
      array->alloc = MAX (array->alloc, MIN_ARRAY_SIZE);
      array->pdata = g_realloc (array->pdata, sizeof (gpointer) * array->alloc); // here
      if (G_UNLIKELY (g_mem_gc_friendly))
        for ( ; old_alloc < array->alloc; old_alloc++)
          array->pdata [old_alloc] = NULL;
    }
}

void
g_ptr_array_add (GPtrArray *array,
                 gpointer   data)
{
  GRealPtrArray *rarray = (GRealPtrArray *)array;

  g_return_if_fail (rarray);

  g_ptr_array_maybe_expand (rarray, 1);

  rarray->pdata[rarray->len++] = data;
}
```

Provide your own locking using, for example, [`GMutex`](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-Threads.html#g-mutex-init).